# socket.io send packet to sender only

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have yet to figure out how to directly respond to only the sender using socket.io

I have learned that io.sockets.emit sends to all clients but I wont to send information back to the sender.

code:

```
socket.on('login', function (data) {
    db.users.find({username: cc.lowerCase(data.username)}, function(err, users) {
      if (users.length > 0) {
        users.forEach( function(user) {
          console.log(user.length);
          if (user.password == data.password) {
            io.sockets.emit('login', { username: user.username });
          } else {
            io.sockets.emit('error', { message: "Wrong username or password!" });
          }
        });
      } else {
        io.sockets.emit('error', { message: "Wrong username or password!" });
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

When your server listens, you usually get a socket at the "connection" event :

```
require('socket.io').on('connect', function(socket){
```

A socket connects 2 points : the client and the server. When you emit on this socket, you emit to this specific client.

Example :

```
var io = require('socket.io');
io.on('connect', function(socket){
    socket.on('A', function(something){
        // we just received a message
        // let's respond to *that* client :
        socket.emit('B', somethingElse);
    });
});
```

Be careful that those are two different calls :

- `socket.emit` : emit to just one socket
- `io.sockets.emit` : emit to all sockets

Comment: For some reason in my case all clients receive the message instead of just the sender. I updated my post with some code. Can you see something wrong?

Comment: @user3577360 Don't use `io.sockets.emit` but `socket.emit`.

Comment: As soon as I use `socket.emit` within a `socket.on`-handler I get an `unhandled error event`. I already tried to hook a `socket.on("error", function(){})` but to no avail... Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: How come you're listening to the `connect` event in your code whereas in the text it says to listen to the `connection` event? Are these two different events? Thanks!

Comment: @Crashalot [look here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/874a4a8535e696f81e9ac54f107c3fb18fb565de/lib/namespace.js#L174) : you can use one or the other

Answer (score 45):

### Simple example

The syntax is confusing in socketio. Also, every socket is automatically connected to their own room with the id `socket.id` (this is how private chat works in socketio, they use rooms).

**Send to the sender and noone else**

```
socket.emit('hello', msg);
```

**Send to everyone *including* the sender(if the sender is in the room) in *the room "my room"***

```
io.to('my room').emit('hello', msg);
```

**Send to everyone *except* the sender(if the sender is in the room) in *the room "my room"***

```
socket.broadcast.to('my room').emit('hello', msg);
```

**Send to everyone in *every room*, *including* the sender**

```
io.emit('hello', msg); // short version

io.sockets.emit('hello', msg);
```

**Send to specific socket only (private chat)**

```
socket.broadcast.to(otherSocket.id).emit('hello', msg);
```

Comment: send to everyone in a room including the sender ->  `io.in(room).emit(/* ... */);`

Answer (score 1):

late but better than never ;)

I had smth like this:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.emit('some event', data);
    socket.on('private event', function(message){
        this.emit('other private event', message);
    }
}
```

After some testing, I realized that 'this.emit' inside 'private event' closure send back only to sender. So i tried 'this.broadcast.emit', which send the message to all connected except the sender. I believe this is what you want from your code.