# Socket.io, message to yourself

Tags: javascript, socket.io

Socket.io doesn't display messages send on yourself ip.
For example

```
var id = 333;
socket.broadcast.to(id).emit('user', user);
```

It working good, but message is only in client #333, but user than sent message, do not have a copy in the message client.

I wanted to solve in this way, but it does not work

```
socket.broadcast.to(socket.id).emit('user', user);
```

Why?

Comment: I'm not quite following what you're trying to accomplish here. `socket.id` is the socket id (no waaayyy) of the current user. Can you elaborate on the issue?

Comment: @SterlingArcher All my user are identified by socket.id, but message is only for the recipient ,not the sender.

Comment: I don't get it... what would you like to happen? Please add some examples of input and output of what you would like to happen.

Comment: @Mathias
socket.id  =  sender id
After clicking on the USER message is relayed was directly to him, as on Facebook . The problem is that the message reaches the recipient but not displayed in the window sender. Therefore wants to pass a message to socket.id , which is the identifier of the sender .

Socket.io not transmit messages to socket.id

Comment: @Emerceen you could consider making a room for the users, and use "io.sockets.in(room).emit" which will send to all in room including sender

Comment: You can add the following: `socket.to(socket.id).emit('user', user);` (remove `broadcast`)

Answer (score 0):

Without more code its hard to say what you want but one thing is certain in order to send a message to a single user you must use that `socket` object and use `socket.emit`

As far as i know `broadcast` is only used to tell everyone except for yourself.

What i usually do when it comes to keeping track of users is i have the following:

```
    var userList = [];
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on('userData', function (userDetails) {
        userDetails.socket = socket;
        userList[userDetails.id] = userDetails
    });
});
```

Basicly when a user connects to my socket and the page for the user is fully loaded it sends its id (or a token if you wish) i then map the user's `socket` into the list  so i can quickly pick it up again if i wish to send to that user.

---

An example could be:

`user.id = 33` connects to our server

Once loaded the users emits to our server `userData` function

The socket is then taken and put into the list at row `33`

When we need to we can this use the following code to get the users `socket`:

```
socket = userList[33];
```

or if we have the object:

```
socket = userList[user.id];
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can use `socket.emit('message')`.

`socket.emit:` Emit for only one socket.

Hope this will help you. You can also check out this link: [socket.io send packet to sender only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24100218/socket-io-send-packet-to-sender-only)